# Lucene BooleanQuery

Tags: hibernate, search, lucene, hibernate-search, analyzer

How to use booleanQuery with StandardAnalyzer in Lucene Search?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presume you are referring to parsing boolean queries using the QueryParser object, correct? The [Lucene query syntax documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Boolean%20operators) should have everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

According to the document, boolean queries should be created once by BooleanQuery.QueryBuilder and then considered immutable. See [BooleanQuery.Builder.add(org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanClause)](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.Builder.html#add(org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanClause))

The code example can be found by http://programtalk.com/java-api-usage-examples/org.apache.lucene.util.QueryBuilder/
and one example given is:

```
public Query parse(Type type, String fieldName, Object value) throws IOException {
    final String field;
    MappedFieldType fieldType = context.fieldMapper(fieldName);
    if (fieldType != null) {
        field = fieldType.name();
    } else {
        field = fieldName;
    }
    /*
     * If the user forced an analyzer we really don't care if they are
     * searching a type that wants term queries to be used with query string
     * because the QueryBuilder will take care of it. If they haven't forced
     * an analyzer then types like NumberFieldType that want terms with
     * query string will blow up because their analyzer isn't capable of
     * passing through QueryBuilder.
     */
    boolean noForcedAnalyzer = this.analyzer == null;
    if (fieldType != null && fieldType.tokenized() == false && noForcedAnalyzer) {
        return blendTermQuery(new Term(fieldName, value.toString()), fieldType);
    }
    Analyzer analyzer = getAnalyzer(fieldType);
    assert analyzer != null;
    MatchQueryBuilder builder = new MatchQueryBuilder(analyzer, fieldType);
    builder.setEnablePositionIncrements(this.enablePositionIncrements);
    Query query = null;
    switch(type) {
        case BOOLEAN:
            if (commonTermsCutoff == null) {
                query = builder.createBooleanQuery(field, value.toString(), occur);
            } else {
                query = builder.createCommonTermsQuery(field, value.toString(), occur, occur, commonTermsCutoff, fieldType);
            }
            break;
        case PHRASE:
            query = builder.createPhraseQuery(field, value.toString(), phraseSlop);
            break;
        case PHRASE_PREFIX:
            query = builder.createPhrasePrefixQuery(field, value.toString(), phraseSlop, maxExpansions);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("No type found for [" + type + "]");
    }
    if (query == null) {
        return zeroTermsQuery();
    } else {
        return query;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`BooleanQuery. BooleanQuery` is a container of Boolean clauses, that are optional, required or prohibited subqueries.  You can normally add a clause to `BooleanQuery` making use of an API method that looks like:

public void add(Query query, boolean required, boolean prohibited)